# Capturing table elements in blueprism

Tags: capture, blueprism

I'm trying to capture a table element of a web application. This element is a search result. I want to browse through rows and select a particular row item from the searched results. Any helps please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a concept of dynamic path to element here.

That would be my approach to that problem:

1. Spy a whole table using Application modeler
2. Use "Read" stage to get a Path to that element. It can be for example

"/HTML/BODY(1)/FORM(1)/DIV(3)/DIV(4)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(3)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)"

I'd store it in [Path_to_the_table] data item.

3. Spy any element, and disable all attributes used to find it. I'd choose an attribute "path" and set it's "match type" to dynamic.
4. Look into a path to the element that you want to use - in my example that's:
   /HTML/BODY(1)/FORM(1)/DIV(3)/DIV(4)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(3)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/**TR(2)**/TD(3)/UL(1)/LI(1)/IMG(1)"

Please note, that the part to the table is exactly the same. The "TR(2)" part marked in bold says the row that the element resides.

5. Make a data item, for example [Row_number], that says a row that you want to check.
6. Make a new "read" stage, that tries to read a value from dynamic element from point 3.
7. As a dynamic element I'd use a path from point 2, and a string from point 4. Please see example below:

**[Path_to_the_table]**&"/TBODY(1)/TR("&**[Row_number]**&"2)/TD(3)/UL(1)/LI(1)/IMG(1)"

That way i can read the value of the element, from the row that I choose.

Comment: This way i can read the contents. However, how can i get the upper bounds for the captured table. Say, the number of rows and columns of the table element

Comment: Hey, that's another question. Please mark that as completed and ask a new one and I'll gladly answer.

Comment: Either loop until exception or read table to collection and use count rows

Comment: Hi, if i want to click/open the element after reading, is it possible? I want to click on the elements dynamically.